# How do I get part of my JSON from a response

Tags: node.js, json

I have the below JSON response in the body of an HTTP GET.

```
{
    "id": "43131",
    "platform": {
        "name": "eu-west-1",
        "endpoint": "https://example.com"
    },
    "token": "W563YGpTw6bVJA"
}
```

However when parsing it, when I try to get the token, I get undefined to the console.

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  let data = JSON.stringify(body); 


  console.log(data[0]["token"]);
```

I also tried

```
console.log(data["token"]);
```

&

```
console.log(data.token);
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

data.length works fine so no problem with JSON format.

Comment: Is the API returning an object? if so, remove the line `let data = JSON.stringify(body); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using JSON.parse() to get a parsed JSON object.

Comment: Great thanks. Is there a better way then what I am doing?

     let data = JSON.stringify(body); 
     var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
  
      console.log(jsonResponse.token);

Comment: If your "body" is already a string, you do not need to call JSON.stringify().

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. Had no error just got nothing!

Comment: Likely the string was not a JSON string. You could use the following link to test your string. It has some helpful documentation as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify